# How do I load spark config for mlflow-experiment on local environment?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mlflow

I could find loading mlflow experiment format would be as easy as

`df = spark.read.format("mlflow-experiment").load()`

But how do I load the spark config?
Calling mlflow-experiment would give me

```
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: mlflow-experiment. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

I tried to add `.config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mlflow.mlflow-spark")` but this does not work either.

Comment: Are you running this on Databricks or somewhere else?

Comment: i ran it on my local ubuntu

Comment: `mlflow-experiment` is only available as a Spark data source on Databricks, so it will not work on your local ubuntu